# Add imageview style in code

Tags: android, imageview

I want create few imageviews in array from code.
I try this,but app force stop.

```
ImageView imgs[];
    imgs=new ImageView[10];
    imgs[0].setLayoutParams(lp);
    imgs[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.drvo1);
    rl.addView(imgs[0]);
```

Comment: Could you post more of the code ? The log of the stack would be useful too in order to help you.

Comment: Could you post your stack trace (logs)? and more code in order to help you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting logcat is very helpful when you have a crash. However, here you have never initialized  `barriers[0]` so you get a `NPE` when you try to run a function on it like

```
 barriers[0].setLayoutParams(lp);
```

You initialize the `Array`

```
imgs=new ImageView[10];
```

but not the first element. You need something like

```
ImageView imgs[];
imgs=new ImageView[10];
imgs[0] = new ImageView(this)  // initialize it here somehow
imgs[0].setLayoutParams(lp);
imgs[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.drvo1);
rl.addView(imgs[0]);
```

Comment: I still don't see it. If you think I'm missing something then please post the logcat.